# Обнуление ссылок

Tags: java, null

```
A a1 = new A("10");
A a2 = new A("20");
a2 = a1;
a1 = null;
```

Подскажите, почему после зануления а1, а2 не будет равна  null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если не техническим языком:

Есть человек Андрей и Сергей.

- Андрею ты говоришь: смотри на 10-ый этаж вооооон того дома. А Сергею говоришь - а ты смотри на 20-ый этаж.
- Потом ты говоришь Сергею: хватит смотреть на 20 этаж! Смотри тоже на 10-ый. Туда же, куда и Андрей
- Теперь говоришь Андрею: хватит смотреть, иди восвояси. Андрей обиженно уходит, но Сергей всё также продолжает смотреть.

Comment: Спасибо, классный пример! 
то есть для ссылочных типов присвоение это так же просто копирование значения?

Comment: разобрался да! мы просто получаем копию ссылки при присвоении

Comment: @dvisotskiy нет, это не копирование значения. Просто когда мы говорим переменной сделаться `null`, то мы просто "отвязываем" её от просмотра в ту область, куда она раньше смотрела. Говорим это только одной конкретной переменной. То есть `null` это как бы  уничтожение точечно, одной переменной, а не сразу всех... Поэтому другая переменная так и остается привязана к тому адресу, к которому ей сказали, пока ей тоже в голову не стрельнут null'ом